# jquery each or custom checkbox question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem on the result and i'm already tired of solving.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$.fn.op_checkbox = function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).wrap('<div class="op_checkbox"></div>');
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="op_check_on_off">&nbsp;</div>');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.op_check_on_off').addClass('op_check_on');
    }
    else {
        $('.op_check_on_off').addClass('op_check_off');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').op_checkbox();
});
```

Result

```
<div class="op_checkbox">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="display: none;">
    <div class="op_check_on_off op_check_on">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="op_checkbox">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="op_check_on_off op_check_on">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The result of first checkbox is copied in 2nd checkbox, the result should be:

```
<div class="op_checkbox">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="display: none;">
    <div class="op_check_on_off op_check_on">&nbsp;</div> <!-- on here -->
</div>
<div class="op_checkbox">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="op_check_on_off op_check_off">&nbsp;</div> <!-- off here -->
</div>
```

What is the reason and problem of this? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside of function `op_checkbox()` is array-like jQuery object, so you should process each object with loop like this:

```
$.fn.op_checkbox = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.hide()
             .wrap('<div class="op_checkbox"></div>')
             .parent().append('<div class="op_check_on_off">&nbsp;</div>');

        if($this.is(':checked')) {
            $this.parent().find('.op_check_on_off').addClass('op_check_on');
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().find('.op_check_on_off').addClass('op_check_off');
        }
    });    
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').op_checkbox();
});
```

And I refactored some code.

1. Inside of `fn` function, `this` is already jQuery object so you don't need to wrap like `$(this)`.
2. Used jQuery chain.
3. Cached `$(this)`. This can improve performance(though it's small improvement).

Comment: I dont think this has solved the problem because the actual problem lies in $('.op_check_on_off') selector. @arba - Please check my answer

Comment: $('.op_check_on_off').addClass('op_check_on'); should be $(this).parent().find('div').addClass('op_check_on'); from the answer of rkw

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two problems currently in your code.  Sangdol helped address the issue that comes with the scoping of $(this), and Shankar helped with the issue of your selector when you are adding the class.  http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/DZYFN/

```
$('.check').each( function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).wrap('<div class="op_checkbox"></div>');
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="op_check_on_off">&nbsp;</div>');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().find('div').addClass('op_check_on');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().find('div').addClass('op_check_off');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.fn.op_checkbox = function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).wrap('<div class="op_checkbox"></div>');
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="op_check_on_off">&nbsp;</div>');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().find('.op_check_on_off').addClass('op_check_on');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().find('.op_check_on_off').addClass('op_check_off');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').op_checkbox();
});
```

Comment: This isn't working. The `$(this).is(':checked')` will check just first checkbox and the `$(this).parent().find('.op_check_on_off').addClass('op_check_on');` will called for both checkboxes simultaneously.

Comment: It will not be called for both because $(this).parent() will control it.